# Flicker when animating a burger menu on WebKit

Tags: html, css, transition, flicker, hamburger-menu

I am animating a burger menu changing the `margin` and `width` of two divs (with transition), and in the meantime, a ***burger icon*** it is animated switching the class `is-active`.

The result, as you can see, is a flicker effect in the content of the burger menu (the ***green*** area):
http://www.codeply.com/go/g7Zp98paz5

Executing the burger button: you can see that, for some miliseconds, the ***green*** area dissapears.
Executing the toggle button: you can see that there are no jumps.

I only reproduce it in Google Chrome.

What is it happening? How can I fix this strange behaviour?

I am using this lib: https://github.com/callmenick/Animating-Hamburger-Icons

Comment: Use the first button (the animated one), with toggle button should work, but with the first one we have a flicker in the green area. I use Chrome 54 as well

Comment: It happens to me, too. Version 54.0.2840.99 for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be be something to do with the rotations; commenting them out makes the transition work correctly:

```
/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  /*transform: rotate(45deg);*/
}

.c-hamburger--htx.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
/*  transform: rotate(-45deg);*/
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about what whould those rotations would be supposed to do:  they don't seem to be part of the transition, since it works without them; they also do nothing on FF (looks the same with or without them), and on Chrome, they cause the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is really strange @Haroldo_OK and very frustrating

Comment: I would think those were put there by mistake, and could be safely removed.